# cómo corregir este problema al cargar GGPLOT2 en R Studio?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy teniendo problemas para cargar el paquete GGPLOT2 en R Studio ya que al parecer a desaparecido del CRAN.

No lo puedo cargar ni con la función install.packages(), ni desde la consola.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Ahora sólo existe el gplot2movies pero que es una base de datos de películas. Nada que ver.

Estoy intentando también instalar alguna versión antigua, del paquete ggplot2.

Para ello he cargado el paquete remotes, ya que vamos a emplear una función llamada install_version(). En esta función hay que especificar el paquete y la versión, tal y como se ve a continuación.

install_version("ggplot2", version = "3.3.6")

he hecho este proceso y tampoco me sale. ¿Cómo puedo ver las versiones de ggplot2 que existen en CRAN, más allá de link que me habeis pasado?

> Error: error al leer desde conexión * removing
> 'C:/Users/SILVIA/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/4.0/ggplot2'
> Warning messages: 1: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘cli’ had
> non-zero exit status 2: In i.p(...) : installation of package ‘tibble’
> had non-zero exit status 3: In i.p(...) : installation of package
> ‘C:/Users/SILVIA/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2L3w8w/remotes3c98715f3eb6/ggplot2’
> had non-zero exit status > library("ggplot2") Error in
> library("ggplot2") : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
>
> > library("cli")
> > library("tibble")
> > library("ggplot2")
> > He probado las librerias "cli" y "tibble" y se cargan sin problema. El error sigue saliendo en ggplot2.
> > library("cli")
> > library("tibble")
> > library("ggplot2")
> > Error in library("ggplot2") : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’

tras ejecutar de nuevo los paquetes, ahora me sale lo siguiente:

In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
there is no package called ‘ggplot2’

Comment: No, ggplot sigue en CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html, te sugiero, que agregues el texto completo del error.  Sino prueba esto `install.packages("ggplot2", method = "libcurl")`

Comment: El fallo de instalación ocurre instalando las dependencias `cli` y `tibble`. Prueba la instalación de esos paquetes por separado para identificar el error con mayor detalle

Comment: @aldo_tapia, gracias por la sugerencia. Acabo de probar y a pesar de cargar esas librerias correctamente, me sigue dando error ggplot2.

Comment: @santonla después de instalar las dependencias, volviste a instalar ggplot2? Ya que el mensaje te indica que no existe (que es lo mismo a no estar instalado)

Comment: Sí, he intantado instalar el paquete de varias formas. También pensaba que podía ser un tema de Rtools, y lo he reinstalado, pero nada.

Comment: Error: error al leer desde conexión
* removing 'C:/Users/SILVIA/OneDrive/Documentos/R/win-library/4.0/ggplot2'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/SILVIA/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpATlulW/remotes323c4fc4892/ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: He desinstalado R y R Studio y los he vuelto a instalar. Además, de instalar también R Tools. Parece que ahora funciona :)